# Remapping JNDI resources in a Java Enterprise Application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

We have a common web module (foo.war) we'd like to deploy as a WAR in a number of different EARs.  foo.war accesses the database via a JNDI datasource that foo knows by the name `jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE`

But for each application XXX, this datasource must be remapped to the the datasource associated with the XXX application, that is `jdbc/XXX-DATASOURCE`.

foo.war has the following in its web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I had thought that I could use the following entries in `glassfish-application.xml` in the XXX project to remap this:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/XXX-DATASOURCE</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

but when I deploy the XXX app to glassfish, I get the messages:

```
This app [xxx-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] has no resource reference by the name of [jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE]
DPL8007: Unsupported deployment descriptors element jndi-name value jdbc/XXX-DATASOURCE
```

Is there some way I can set up a translation at the EAR-level for the resource defined in the web.xml?
Where is glassfish looking for the resource reference?
Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I can declare the resource at the EAR-level: in the `application.xml`.  Where I was going wrong was that I was originally using an old version of the application.xml schema.  When I changed it to `version="6"`, I was then able to add a `resource-ref` which was then also accepted by glassfish in the `glassfish-application.xml`.

But there's a complication: I can only declare application-level (`java:app/`) resources in the application.xml whereas my Datasources in web.xml are component-level (`java:comp/env/`).

To work around this, I map the resource to an application-level resource in the `glassfish-web.xml` and then remap it to the correct name in `glassfish-application.xml`:

foo web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

foo glassfish-web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>java:app/FOO-DATASOURCE</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

XXX application.xml (version="6"):

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>java:app/jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>CONTAINER</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

XXX glassfish-application.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>java:app/jdbc/FOO-DATASOURCE</res-ref-name>
  <jndi-name>java:app/jdbc/XXX-DATASOURCE</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

This worked but I don't really know why a resource that would be called `jdbc/XXX-DATASOURCE` in a web.xml file ends up being equivalent to a resource called `java:app/jdbc/XXX-DATASOURCE` in an application.xml file.